# Filter Hours based on different timings

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, filter

I want a generic javascript function which should accept an array of objects.
Each object has an hours property which is an array ,can be seen in below code.
Every hours shows different timings for each day.
Now i need to Filter the hours. if the timings (from and to )are same from Monday to Tuesday then it should display : M-T:9-5PM W-T:9-9PM Sat-Sun:Closed
If timings are same from Monday to Friday and diff on sat or sun, it should display M-F:9-5 PM and Sat:9-9PM and sun:closed.

I should return data in the array so that i can display in below format in UI.
It should return array but containing this data,so that can be easily rendered using loop on front end.

Ex:Im giving the two objects inside an array.
Overall I want to show the differenttimings only once .

Comment: What have you tried ? Can you post your code here ?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
const myHours = myData.map(item => {
  const aggHours = item.hours.reduce((aggArr, obj) => {    
    const len = aggArr.length;
    const last = len - 1;
    //console.log(len, obj, aggArr)
    if (len == 0){
      aggArr.push({...obj, dayStr: obj.day});
    }
    else if (aggArr[last].fromHour == obj.fromHour
              && aggArr[last].toHour == obj.toHour) {
      aggArr[last].dayStr = aggArr[last].day + " - " + obj.day;
    }
    else {
      aggArr.push({...obj, dayStr: obj.day});
    }       
    
    return aggArr;
  }, []); 
  
  return {id: item.id, aggHours: aggHours.map(elem => {
    if (elem.closed){
      return {day: elem.dayStr, time: 'closed'};
    }
    else {
      return {day: elem.dayStr, time: elem.fromHour + ' - ' + elem.toHour};
    }
  })};
});

console.log(myHours);
```

```html
<script id="loadData">

const myData = [
  {
      "phones":[
          {
              "id":"dealer/phones/phone_0?sales=department",
              "dialIn":"8777931407",
              "region":"+1",
              "areaCode":"877",
              "carrier":"793",
              "subscriber":"1407",
              "nodeUri":{
                  "query":"sales=department",
                  "params":{
                      "sales":"department"
                  },
                  "domainName":"dealer",
                  "modelName":"phones",
                  "instanceID":"phone_0"
              }
          }
      ],
      "address":{
          "street1":"2101 Pennsylvania Ave",
          "street2":null,
          "city":"Wilmington",
          "state":"DE",
          "country":"US",
          "postalCode":"19806",
          "latitude":39.7578416,
          "longitude":-75.5688727,
          "timeZone":"America/New_York",
          "region":"NORTHEAST",
          "county":"NEW CASTLE"
      },
      "id":"dealer/department/sales",
      "displayName":"Sales By Appointment",
      "name":"sales",
      "email":"qacobaltsanitized@hotmail.com",
      "phoneNumber":"8777931407",
      "hours":[
          {
              "fromHour":"09:00",
              "toHour":"17:00",
              "day":"Monday"
          },
          {
              "fromHour":"09:00",
              "toHour":"17:00",
              "day":"Tuesday"
          },
          {
              "fromHour":"09:00",
              "toHour":"17:00",
              "day":"Wednesday"
          },
          {
              "fromHour":"09:00",
              "toHour":"17:00",
              "day":"Thursday"
          },
          {
              "fromHour":"09:00",
              "toHour":"17:00",
              "day":"Friday"
          },
          {
              "fromHour":"09:00",
              "toHour":"17:00",
              "day":"Saturday"
          },
          {
              "closed":true,
              "fromHour":"Closed",
              "toHour":"Closed",
              "day":"Sunday"
          }
      ],
      "hoursOfOperationTitle":"Hours Of Operation",
      "nodeUri":{
          "query":"",
          "domainName":"dealer",
          "modelName":"department",
          "instanceID":"sales"
      }
  }
  ,
  {
      "phones":[
          {
              "id":"dealer/phones/phone_0?service=department",
              "dialIn":"3024828359",
              "region":"+1",
              "areaCode":"302",
              "carrier":"482",
              "subscriber":"8359",
              "nodeUri":{
                  "query":"service=department",
                  "params":{
                      "service":"department"
                  },
                  "domainName":"dealer",
                  "modelName":"phones",
                  "instanceID":"phone_0"
              }
          }
      ],
      "address":{
          "street1":"2101 Pennsylvania Ave",
          "street2":null,
          "city":"Wilmington",
          "state":"DE",
          "country":"US",
          "postalCode":"19806",
          "latitude":39.7578416,
          "longitude":-75.5688727,
          "timeZone":"America/New_York",
          "region":"NORTHEAST",
          "county":"NEW CASTLE"
      },
      "dynamicAttr":{
          "itemprop":"department",
          "itemtype":"//schema.org/AutoRepair"
      },
      "displayNameAttr":{
          "itemprop":"name"
      },
      "id":"dealer/department/service",
      "displayName":"Service ",
      "name":"service",
      "email":"qacobaltsanitized@hotmail.com",
      "phoneNumber":"3024828359",
      "hours":[
          {
              "fromHour":"07:00",
              "toHour":"16:00",
              "day":"Monday"
          },
          {
              "fromHour":"07:00",
              "toHour":"16:00",
              "day":"Tuesday"
          },
          {
              "fromHour":"07:00",
              "toHour":"16:00",
              "day":"Wednesday"
          },
          {
              "fromHour":"07:00",
              "toHour":"16:00",
              "day":"Thursday"
          },
          {
              "fromHour":"07:00",
              "toHour":"16:00",
              "day":"Friday"
          },
          {
              "fromHour":"07:00",
              "toHour":"16:00",
              "day":"Saturday"
          },
          {
              "closed":true,
              "fromHour":"Closed",
              "toHour":"Closed",
              "day":"Sunday"
          }
      ],
      "nodeUri":{
          "query":"",
          "domainName":"dealer",
          "modelName":"department",
          "instanceID":"service"
      }
  }
]

</script>
```

Output:

```js
[
  {
    "id": "dealer/department/sales",
    "aggHours": [
      {
        "day": "Monday - Saturday",
        "time": "09:00 - 17:00"
      },
      {
        "day": "Sunday",
        "time": "closed"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "dealer/department/service",
    "aggHours": [
      {
        "day": "Monday - Saturday",
        "time": "07:00 - 16:00"
      },
      {
        "day": "Sunday",
        "time": "closed"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Second example:**

```js
const myHours = myData.map(item => {
  const aggHours = item.hours.reduce((aggArr, obj) => {    
    const len = aggArr.length;
    const last = len - 1;
    //console.log(len, obj, aggArr)
    if (len == 0){
      aggArr.push({...obj, dayStr: obj.day});
    }
    else if (aggArr[last].fromHour == obj.fromHour
              && aggArr[last].toHour == obj.toHour) {
      aggArr[last].dayStr = aggArr[last].day + " - " + obj.day;
    }
    else {
      aggArr.push({...obj, dayStr: obj.day});
    }       
    
    return aggArr;
  }, []); 
  
  return {id: item.id, aggHours: aggHours.map(elem => {
    if (elem.closed){
      return {day: elem.dayStr, time: 'closed'};
    }
    else {
      return {day: elem.dayStr, time: elem.fromHour + ' - ' + elem.toHour};
    }
  })};
});

console.log(myHours);
```

```html
<script id="loadData">

const myData = [
  {
      "phones":[
          {
              "id":"dealer/phones/phone_0?sales=department",
              "dialIn":"8777931407",
              "region":"+1",
              "areaCode":"877",
              "carrier":"793",
              "subscriber":"1407",
              "nodeUri":{
                  "query":"sales=department",
                  "params":{
                      "sales":"department"
                  },
                  "domainName":"dealer",
                  "modelName":"phones",
                  "instanceID":"phone_0"
              }
          }
      ],
      "address":{
          "street1":"2101 Pennsylvania Ave",
          "street2":null,
          "city":"Wilmington",
          "state":"DE",
          "country":"US",
          "postalCode":"19806",
          "latitude":39.7578416,
          "longitude":-75.5688727,
          "timeZone":"America/New_York",
          "region":"NORTHEAST",
          "county":"NEW CASTLE"
      },
      "id":"dealer/department/sales",
      "displayName":"Sales By Appointment",
      "name":"sales",
      "email":"qacobaltsanitized@hotmail.com",
      "phoneNumber":"8777931407",
      "hours":[
          {
              "fromHour":"09:00",
              "toHour":"17:00",
              "day":"Monday"
          },
          {
              "fromHour":"09:00",
              "toHour":"17:00",
              "day":"Tuesday"
          },
          {
              "fromHour":"09:00",
              "toHour":"17:00",
              "day":"Wednesday"
          },
          {
              "fromHour":"09:00",
              "toHour":"17:00",
              "day":"Thursday"
          },
          {
              "fromHour":"09:00",
              "toHour":"17:00",
              "day":"Friday"
          },
          {
              "closed":true,
              "fromHour":"Closed",
              "toHour":"Closed",
              "day":"Saturday"
          },
          {
              "closed":true,
              "fromHour":"Closed",
              "toHour":"Closed",
              "day":"Sunday"
          }
      ],
      "hoursOfOperationTitle":"Hours Of Operation",
      "nodeUri":{
          "query":"",
          "domainName":"dealer",
          "modelName":"department",
          "instanceID":"sales"
      }
  }
  ,
  {
      "phones":[
          {
              "id":"dealer/phones/phone_0?service=department",
              "dialIn":"3024828359",
              "region":"+1",
              "areaCode":"302",
              "carrier":"482",
              "subscriber":"8359",
              "nodeUri":{
                  "query":"service=department",
                  "params":{
                      "service":"department"
                  },
                  "domainName":"dealer",
                  "modelName":"phones",
                  "instanceID":"phone_0"
              }
          }
      ],
      "address":{
          "street1":"2101 Pennsylvania Ave",
          "street2":null,
          "city":"Wilmington",
          "state":"DE",
          "country":"US",
          "postalCode":"19806",
          "latitude":39.7578416,
          "longitude":-75.5688727,
          "timeZone":"America/New_York",
          "region":"NORTHEAST",
          "county":"NEW CASTLE"
      },
      "dynamicAttr":{
          "itemprop":"department",
          "itemtype":"//schema.org/AutoRepair"
      },
      "displayNameAttr":{
          "itemprop":"name"
      },
      "id":"dealer/department/service",
      "displayName":"Service ",
      "name":"service",
      "email":"qacobaltsanitized@hotmail.com",
      "phoneNumber":"3024828359",
      "hours":[
          {
              "fromHour":"07:00",
              "toHour":"16:00",
              "day":"Monday"
          },
          {
              "fromHour":"07:00",
              "toHour":"16:00",
              "day":"Tuesday"
          },
          {
              "fromHour":"07:00",
              "toHour":"16:00",
              "day":"Wednesday"
          },
          {
              "fromHour":"07:00",
              "toHour":"16:00",
              "day":"Thursday"
          },
          {
              "fromHour":"07:00",
              "toHour":"11:00",
              "day":"Friday"
          },
          {
              "fromHour":"07:00",
              "toHour":"11:00",
              "day":"Saturday"
          },
          {
              "fromHour":"07:00",
              "toHour":"11:00",
              "day":"Sunday"
          }
      ],
      "nodeUri":{
          "query":"",
          "domainName":"dealer",
          "modelName":"department",
          "instanceID":"service"
      }
  }
]

</script>
```

Output:

```js
[
  {
    "id": "dealer/department/sales",
    "aggHours": [
      {
        "day": "Monday - Friday",
        "time": "09:00 - 17:00"
      },
      {
        "day": "Saturday - Sunday",
        "time": "closed"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "dealer/department/service",
    "aggHours": [
      {
        "day": "Monday - Thursday",
        "time": "07:00 - 16:00"
      },
      {
        "day": "Friday - Sunday",
        "time": "07:00 - 11:00"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Third example:**

```js
const myHours = myData.map(item => {
  const aggHours = item.hours.reduce((aggObj, obj) => {    
    const times = obj.fromHour + ' - ' + obj.toHour;
    if (aggObj[times]){
      aggObj[times].days.push(obj.day);
    }
    else {
      aggObj[times] = {...obj, days: [obj.day]};
    }       
    
    return aggObj;
  }, {}); 
  
  return {id: item.id, aggHours: Object.values(aggHours).map(elem => {
    if (elem.closed){
      return {day: elem.days, time: 'closed'};
    }
    else {
      return {day: elem.days, time: elem.fromHour + ' - ' + elem.toHour};
    }
  })};
});

console.log(myHours);
```

```html
<script id="loadData">

const myData = [
  {
      "phones":[
          {
              "id":"dealer/phones/phone_0?sales=department",
              "dialIn":"8777931407",
              "region":"+1",
              "areaCode":"877",
              "carrier":"793",
              "subscriber":"1407",
              "nodeUri":{
                  "query":"sales=department",
                  "params":{
                      "sales":"department"
                  },
                  "domainName":"dealer",
                  "modelName":"phones",
                  "instanceID":"phone_0"
              }
          }
      ],
      "address":{
          "street1":"2101 Pennsylvania Ave",
          "street2":null,
          "city":"Wilmington",
          "state":"DE",
          "country":"US",
          "postalCode":"19806",
          "latitude":39.7578416,
          "longitude":-75.5688727,
          "timeZone":"America/New_York",
          "region":"NORTHEAST",
          "county":"NEW CASTLE"
      },
      "id":"dealer/department/sales",
      "displayName":"Sales By Appointment",
      "name":"sales",
      "email":"qacobaltsanitized@hotmail.com",
      "phoneNumber":"8777931407",
      "hours":[
          {
              "fromHour":"09:00",
              "toHour":"17:00",
              "day":"Monday"
          },
          {
              "fromHour":"09:00",
              "toHour":"17:00",
              "day":"Tuesday"
          },
          {
              "fromHour":"09:00",
              "toHour":"17:00",
              "day":"Wednesday"
          },
          {
              "fromHour":"09:00",
              "toHour":"17:00",
              "day":"Thursday"
          },
          {
              "fromHour":"09:00",
              "toHour":"17:00",
              "day":"Friday"
          },
          {
              "closed":true,
              "fromHour":"Closed",
              "toHour":"Closed",
              "day":"Saturday"
          },
          {
              "fromHour":"09:00",
              "toHour":"17:00",
              "day":"Sunday"
          }
      ],
      "hoursOfOperationTitle":"Hours Of Operation",
      "nodeUri":{
          "query":"",
          "domainName":"dealer",
          "modelName":"department",
          "instanceID":"sales"
      }
  }
  ,
  {
      "phones":[
          {
              "id":"dealer/phones/phone_0?service=department",
              "dialIn":"3024828359",
              "region":"+1",
              "areaCode":"302",
              "carrier":"482",
              "subscriber":"8359",
              "nodeUri":{
                  "query":"service=department",
                  "params":{
                      "service":"department"
                  },
                  "domainName":"dealer",
                  "modelName":"phones",
                  "instanceID":"phone_0"
              }
          }
      ],
      "address":{
          "street1":"2101 Pennsylvania Ave",
          "street2":null,
          "city":"Wilmington",
          "state":"DE",
          "country":"US",
          "postalCode":"19806",
          "latitude":39.7578416,
          "longitude":-75.5688727,
          "timeZone":"America/New_York",
          "region":"NORTHEAST",
          "county":"NEW CASTLE"
      },
      "dynamicAttr":{
          "itemprop":"department",
          "itemtype":"//schema.org/AutoRepair"
      },
      "displayNameAttr":{
          "itemprop":"name"
      },
      "id":"dealer/department/service",
      "displayName":"Service ",
      "name":"service",
      "email":"qacobaltsanitized@hotmail.com",
      "phoneNumber":"3024828359",
      "hours":[
          {
              "fromHour":"07:00",
              "toHour":"16:00",
              "day":"Monday"
          },
          {
              "fromHour":"07:00",
              "toHour":"16:00",
              "day":"Tuesday"
          },
          {
              "fromHour":"07:00",
              "toHour":"16:00",
              "day":"Wednesday"
          },
          {
              "fromHour":"07:00",
              "toHour":"16:00",
              "day":"Thursday"
          },
          {
              "fromHour":"07:00",
              "toHour":"11:00",
              "day":"Friday"
          },
          {
              "fromHour":"07:00",
              "toHour":"11:00",
              "day":"Saturday"
          },
          {
              "fromHour":"07:00",
              "toHour":"11:00",
              "day":"Sunday"
          }
      ],
      "nodeUri":{
          "query":"",
          "domainName":"dealer",
          "modelName":"department",
          "instanceID":"service"
      }
  }
]

</script>
```

Output:

```js
[
  {
    "id": "dealer/department/sales",
    "aggHours": [
      {
        "day": [
          "Monday",
          "Tuesday",
          "Wednesday",
          "Thursday",
          "Friday",
          "Sunday"
        ],
        "time": "09:00 - 17:00"
      },
      {
        "day": [
          "Saturday"
        ],
        "time": "closed"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "dealer/department/service",
    "aggHours": [
      {
        "day": [
          "Monday",
          "Tuesday",
          "Wednesday",
          "Thursday"
        ],
        "time": "07:00 - 16:00"
      },
      {
        "day": [
          "Friday",
          "Saturday",
          "Sunday"
        ],
        "time": "07:00 - 11:00"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: There is a flaw in the code. For sunday timings, there is always a separate entry even if the sunday timings matches with any of the days.

Comment: Not true? See my second example, the Sunday matches Saturday for sales and you see ``{"day": "Saturday - Sunday", "time": "closed"}`` and for services it matches for Friday and Saturday and you see ``{"day": "Friday - Sunday", "time": "07:00 - 11:00"}``

Comment: Please include your desired output, as a javascript array/object in the question and I can match it no problem. It was not clear exactly what output you needed. My answer was a proof of concept.

Comment: {
id:"dealer/department/service",
aggHours:(3) [
{
day:"Monday - Friday",
time:"07:00 - 16:00"
},
{
day:"Saturday",
time:"07:00 - 19:00"
},
{
day:"Sunday",
time:"07:00 - 16:00"
}
]
}

See this output.Here sunday timing matches with monday to friday timings. But there is a separate entry for sunday.

Comment: yes, but your image https://i.stack.imgur.com/sG4S4.png and your description etc. never included this example, nor did you clearly articulate this. Every shop opening hours I have ever seen, do not add Sunday times to Monday to Friday times, unless Saturday is the same or all 7 days are the same, then you can say "thursday - Sunday: 10- 18" or "everyday: 10-18" or whatever. I have never seen "Monday - Friday, and Sunday: 10-18" but is this what you want? Please define the behaviour you expect and the expected outcome data structure format.

Comment: See my third example, you want to do something like this right? And then format the data something like "Monday - Wednesday, & Friday: 10-18" or "Monday - Friday, & Sunday: 10-18" etc.? Please define clearly in your answer.